# ArgumentParser extend values of positional and optional arguments into same namespace

Tags: python

I'm doing some script which should allow to pass values both as chain of positional arguments and multiple files using optional arguments (`-f` or `--file`). It's easy to implement using `"extend"` action, so I've done something like this:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType

with open("file1.txt", "w") as f1, open("file2.txt", "w") as f2:
    f1.write("arg3")
    f2.write("arg4")

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("pos", nargs="*")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", action="extend", type=FileType())
args = parser.parse_args([
    "arg1",
    "arg2",
    "-f", "file1.txt",
    "--file", "file2.txt"
])
print(args)
```

It works and I got next result:

```py
Namespace(pos=['arg1', 'arg2'], file=['arg3', 'arg4'])
```

Now I have to work with two separate lists which is possible, but I feel like there's a way to let `ArgumentParser` collect all arguments into same list.

What I've already tried:

1. Provide same `dest` for both arguments:

   ```py
   parser = ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("pos", nargs="*", dest="values")
   parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", action="extend", type=FileType(), dest="values")
   ```

   It leads to exception:

   ```
   ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument
   ```
2. Use same name *(which actually worked, but I have to use `-f` and `--file` for optional arguments and renaming positional breaks help)*:

   ```py
   parser = ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("pos", nargs="*")
   parser.add_argument("-p", "--pos", action="extend", type=FileType())
   # Namespace(pos=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'])
   ```

   ```py
   parser = ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("file", nargs="*")
   parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", action="extend", type=FileType())
   # Namespace(file=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'])
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so simple, but it appeared in my head just after I'd finished writing this question... Anyway, I haven't found a similar question, so I'd leave this answer for future researchers.

Idea with `dest` argument is the correct one, the only thing is that we should add it only to optional argument and value have to be equal to name of positional argument.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType

with open("file1.txt", "w") as f1, open("file2.txt", "w") as f2:
    f1.write("arg3")
    f2.write("arg4")

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("pos", nargs="*", action="extend")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", action="extend", type=FileType(), dest="pos")
args = parser.parse_args([
    "arg1",
    "arg2",
    "-f", "file1.txt",
    "--file", "file2.txt"
])
print(args)
```

Output:

```py
Namespace(pos=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'])
```

Comment: Please do not forget to accept your own answer so other people see that this question is solved !